# Does saying "I'm new at programming" make for a good excuse?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes whilst surfing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions, I sometimes see what I quoted above, which goes along the lines of:

> I'm new at ...

Does this count as noise (and if not, an excuse to make someone give an answer)?

Comment: An excuse for *what*? A low-quality question? No. There are no excuses for low-quality questions. If the question is good and the statement of experience level just provides a context for answerers, then it may make sense to leave it in. Otherwise, remove it.

Comment: At best, it is noise.  At worst, it is a sign of a low-quality question.  You should downvote and cast close votes (or flag if you don't have enough rep for close votes).

Comment: I disagree with the statement that it's noise or worse. If someone is new at a specific language, and the question is a valid one and not low-quality, you might put in a little extra effort explaining functionality of built-in functions and such, since the person might have never seen them before. While it's always good to properly explain your answer, this information is useful to me. However, it's not an excuse for anything. Every question on SO should be held to the same quality standards.

Comment: In those cases where the OP has, say, Java but now has a C question, I'm happy to add some extra explanation on the grounds that the OP has a chance of understanding, and acting, on the info.  'I'm new to programming', however, as in 'not a professional or enthusiast programmer', and any such help is likely to result in a vamp blood-trail of 'can you provide an example', 'Please provide the full code' and the like:(